# Eletric Field of a induced sphere

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Suppose I have a conductor sphere, and a point charge at a distance x away from the center of the sphere.

The sphere will be polarized, but what about it field lines of that sphere? Is zero?

I would say yes, with Gauss law, but if is that the case, the point charge will be at equilibrium instead of exist an attractive force.  Im really confused.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have a conductor sphere, and a point charge at a distance x away from the center of the sphere.

The sphere has no net charge I assume?

> The sphere will be polarized, but what about it field lines of that sphere? Is zero?

The *net* flux from the sphere will be zero with any increase in one side being associated with a decrease elsewhere.  But that doesn't mean that the field is equal to zero at every point on the gaussian surface.

> I would say yes, with Gauss law, but if is that the case, the point charge will be at equilibrium instead of exist an attractive force. Im really confused.

A net flux of zero from the sphere does not imply zero force on the charge.  As the induced charges are polarized, some are closer to the test charge and those have a greater effect on the forces.

Comment: "The net flux from the sphere will be zero with any increase in one side being associated with a decrease elsewhere. But that doesn't mean that the field is equal to zero at every point on the gaussian surface." Thats what I was looking for. Why flux=0 doesn't mean E=0 in that case?

Comment: Because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law relates the total charge to the total flux.  It gives you no information about the flux at any particular point, just what the total is.  The flux from an uncharged volume could be all zeros.  Or it could be +5 and -5, or lots of other things.

Answer (score 0):

For a force to exist it is necessary and sufficient to have an electric field at the charge location. A dipole may have a zero net charge, yet it creates a dipole electric field and affects the other charges (as well as itself is affected by the external field sources).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Firstly U need to understand that this is the way the charge is going to be induced
Now for the flux part

[image]

since the charge distribution in the sphere is symmetrical the number of field lines entering is gonna be equal to the number of field lines leaving the gaussian surface hence resulting in zero flux .

But the charge will experience a force because
We know that inside the conductor electric field is zero. So,
E Net= E ind + E ext =0 ⇒ Eind =−Eext= − Kq/r^2 i cap

so now F = qE

Hope it helps Have fun ELecrostating ;)

Comment: So, the force in q is zero?

Comment: thats correct the net charge on the sphere is 0 F= qE q =0 hence F = 0

Comment: DId u get it now?

Comment: I believed that too, but i found this https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/papers/LevinJo11.pdf

Comment: look im sure about the flux part let me check the force

Comment: ok i got it now ill improvise the force part

Comment: ive changed the answer a bit , added the force part too

Comment: Ok, i see now. So there are lines  of field coming out of the sphere surface?

Comment: yes field lines are both coming in and going out its just that they r equal so they cancel